# custom getCellEditor 

Tags: extjs

I use custom CellEditor in my grid:

```
getCellEditor: function(colIndex, rowIndex) {
    var field = this.getDataIndex(colIndex);
    if (field == 'value') {
    if ( type == 3 ) {
        return this.editors['number'];
    }   else if ( type == 1 ) {
        return this.editors['select'];
    }   else if ( type == 4 ) {
        return this.editors['checkbox'];
    }
    }
return Ext.grid.ColumnModel.prototype.getCellEditor.call(this, colIndex, rowIndex);
}
},this);
```

type - this is record.get('type') from grid.store. How to know type in this getCellEditor ?
(I don't want to use global variable :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rowIndex` parameter, so to access the 'type' for the current row in your grid:

```
grid.store.getAt(rowIndex).data.type
```

Comment: This only returns a record.  Once you have the record you'll need to loop through the fields to get the type.

Comment: According to the original question type is a field on the record: "type - this is record.get('type') from grid.store"

Answer (score 0):

You will have need to have defined the type in the field definition, From there, you can use the row index to get the Record.

```
var record = store.getAt(rowIndex);
  for(var i = 0; i<record.fields.length; i++) {
    if(record.fields[i].name == 'Your Field')  {
      alert(record.fields[i].type);
    }
 }
```

This is untested but shows how you can test for the type of a given field in the record